# fsutil file createnew on windows vs dd on linux

Tags: dd, fsutil

As title, I wonder how fsutil in windows can create a really large file so fast. Does it really allocate real cluster for that file or it just writes down file's metadata? Consider two commands below:

```
fsutil file createnew testFile <1Tb>
dd if=/dev/zero of=testFile bs=1024M count=1024
```

So I create a file with 1Tb size, the problem is with fsutil, the file is nearly created immediately, but with dd, it took over 1 hour to complete. 
Therefore, I guess that fsutil only writes metadata to the file header, the real file cluster will expand whenever needed. Do I think right?

Comment: any idea pls ??

Comment: You can create a sparse file with `dd if=/dev/zero of=sparse.bin bs=1 count=0 seek=1024G`

Answer (score 0):

from Microsoft documentation

> ***createnew***
>   Creates a file of the specified name and size, with content that consists of zeroes.

from here, you can say that the file must be all zeros (*[...]with content that consists of zeroes*)

but, if this is truth

```
[...]the file is nearly created immediately[...]
```

I think that you are right: probably, **fsutil** creates the file with bytes marked as free at the time of execution, but doesn't write those bytes

When you use **dd** like this

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=testFile bs=1024M count=1024
```

you are actually writing, "byte by byte", zeros in each byte of the new file

You can do this:

```
fsutil file createnew testFile_fsutil <1Tb>   #(on Windows)

dd if=/dev/zero of=testFile_dd bs=1024M count=1024   #(on Linux)
```

and then, you can see the contents of *testFile_fsutil* on any *hexeditor*, and looking for non-zero bytes, or, more precisely, from Linux you can do *( 1099511627776 bytes = 1 Tebibyte )*:

```
cmp --bytes=1099511627776 testFile_fsutil testFile_dd
```

or

```
cmp --bytes=1099511627776 testFile_fsutil /dev/zero
```

or even using hashes:

```
dd if=/dev/zero bs=1024M count=1024 | sha1sum
```

return

> **fea475204f4ad1348f21fad930a7c721a2858971**

so,

```
dd if=testFile_fsutil bs=1024M count=1024 | sha1sum
```

must return the same.

***Note***: to prove your point much more quickly, you can use a much smaller file for test.